# How to serve static file with Javalin

Tags: java, kotlin, web, javalin

Building a web app with Javalin. How do I display a PDF from my staticfiles folder in the app.post function?

I can't use .getResourceAsStream because it has images, and the function couldn't parse it. I can serve html files using ctx.html but can't find similar for PDF. I can find it manually by typing the file name into the address bar but want to serve it automatically.

Comment: Your PDF is in the static files location, so you don't need any specific logic in a Javalin route. You can just use the static URL directly (no need for `getResourceAsStream`) . For example: `http://your-webapp-root/sample.pdf`. Or, within the app itself, just `/sample.pdf`. It's no different from a static CSS file, JS file, etc.

Comment: (Just to check: You have configured the Javalin static file location, right?)

Answer (score 0):

You can add directory with static files to your Javalin app like this:

```
        Javalin app = Javalin.create(javalinConfig -> {
            javalinConfig.staticFiles.add("/static");//add() accepts path to directory with static files 
        }).start(7070);
```

Now you can simply redirect in the app.post function:

```
        app.post("/", ctx -> ctx.redirect("/fileName.pdf"));
```

"/fileName.pdf" - path to your file in "static" folder